# Exporting java application including database

Tags: java

I've developed a complete java desktop application including MySql db for my first ever professional project. Now i need to hand it over to my client and surprisingly i don't know how to package all the files so that database is also included with its schema,users,table etc.

Comment: The database is exported with the tools provided by the database; IIRC `mysql_dump` or something like that.

Comment: Is the database server supposed to run on the desktop machine or on a separate server? Is the MySQL server already installed on that machine? Do you want to make an installation package? Or do you have physical access to your client's machine and want to install your program manually?

Comment: First of all, apologies for i'm responding too much late, and yes sir i want to have an installation package which would automatically setup JRE and MYsql in client's machine if it does not exist already. Any help would be much more appreciated sir, I've googled a lot but still have no solution..

Comment: @vanje sir, please have a look..